# whatz the error in this gridview row command?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            'Find the checkbox
            Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
            If e.CommandName = "feedback" Then
                Me.Response.Redirect("~/view_feedback.aspx?" & "serv_code=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

**ERROR**

ITS ONLY RETIEVE THE FIRST ROW LABEL5 TEXT TO view_feedback.aspx, even if i select the first row of gridview or i selct last row of gridview ...

Can anybody modify this code so that ..it will transfer the label5 value according to the row selected in gridview1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument.aspx) to the control that caused the postback and has the CommandName "feedback". This CommandArgument ideally is your serv_code.

This CommandArgument can be accessed via the GridViewCommandEventArgs-parameter in the RowCommand-handler.

For example:

```
<asp:Button CommandName="feedback"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("serv_code") %>' id="btnFeedBack" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not do a loop, you should get the selected row, find the label5 and then redirect to the page.

Comment: How to do that ,,, m begineer